# SFML Vector of sprites and Sprite Collision Error

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making a game with C++ and SFML, and I have a serious problem with it.
What I want to make is, when my player(a.k.a. human character) collides with one item, then only that item should be erased. For example, when player collides with 'chicken' item, then only 'chicken' item should be erased, not other items.
However, when I run my program, and when player collides with 'chicken' item, then other items are all erased. And I don't know why. I really need your help. In spite of my poor English, thanks for reading!

And here's my code :

```
     #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
     ...
     using namespace std;
     using namespace sf;
     ...

     int main () {
     ...

     //item Sprites

     Texture bombTex;
     bombTex.loadFromFile("images/bomb.png");
     Sprite bomb;
     ...
     Texture bomb2Tex;
     bomb2Tex.loadFromFile("images/bomb_2.png");
     Sprite bomb_2;
     ...
     Texture cakeTex;
     cakeTex.loadFromFile("images/cake.png");
     Sprite cake;
     ...
     Texture coffeeTex;
     coffeeTex.loadFromFile("images/coffee.png");
     Sprite coffee;
     ...
    Texture chickenTex;
    chickenTex.loadFromFile("images/chicken.png");
    Sprite chicken;
    ...
    Texture pizzaTex;
    pizzaTex.loadFromFile("images/pizza.png");
    Sprite pizza;

    //item array (I made an item array to display & render various items in the game screen.)
    Sprite item[10];
    item[0] = bomb;
    item[1] = coffee;
    item[2] = bomb_2;
    item[3] = chicken;
    item[4] = pizza;

    std::vector<Sprite> items;
    items.push_back(Sprite(item[4]));

    ...

   while (window.isOpen())
  {   ...
      ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        if (humanArr[index].getGlobalBounds().intersects(item[i].getGlobalBounds())) 
        //humanArr[index] is a player Sprite.
        {
            ...
            items.erase(items.begin());
        }
     }
    ...
   window.clear();
    ...
   for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            window.draw(item[i]);
        }

    ...
   window.display();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
    for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        // first problem: you are accessing item[i] instead of items[i]
        if (humanArr[index].getGlobalBounds().intersects(item[i].getGlobalBounds())) 
        {
            ...
            items.erase(items.begin()); // <---------- second problem is here
        }
     }
```

You are not erasing the item you are iterating over, you are instead erasing the first item. You are also accessing the wrong array. I recommend changing the name of `item` to avoid this in the future. Here is how you solve this:

```cpp
    // Pull human bounds out of the loop so that we dont' access them each
    // iteration.
    const humanBounds = humanArr[index];
    for (auto iter = items.begin(); iter != items.end();)
    {
        if (humanBounds.intersects(iter->getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            iter = items.erase(iter); 
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
```

See [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really appreciate that. However, now it works well on first collided item, I mean, the first item erases well when it collides with player, but it doesn't work on following items. Precisely, following items don't erase even if it collides with player. Also, it causes exception error on the last code : 'for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            window.draw(item[i]);
        }'
 Anyway, thanks for your contribution on my project!